# Testing an IF statement with respect to state with Enzyme & Jest doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test this method which is responsible for editing but am able to the lines which replace the **old title** and the **old body** with the new title and body.

This is located in the IF section. Below is the code which implements editing:

```
onEditNote = event => {
  const {
    target: { value: id }
  } = event;
  const obj = {
    title: this.state.title,
    body: this.state.body
  };

  // clear the errors while submitting

  this.setState({ titleError: "", bodyError: "" });

  if (obj.title === "") {
    this.setState({ titleError: "Title empty, please add title" });
  } else if (obj.body === "") {
    this.setState({ bodyError: "Body empty, please add body" });
  } else if (obj.title.length > 20) {
    this.setState({ titleError: "Title is too long." });
  } else {
    this.setState(state => {
      const list = state.notesArray.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          item.title = obj.title;
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          item.body = obj.body;
        }
        return item;
      });

      localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(list));

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      $("#editModal").modal("close");
      this.onSuccessToast("Noted edited successfully.");
      return {
        list,
        title: "",
        body: ""
      };
    });
  }
};
```

These are the lines in the above code which are not covered by the test I implemented:

```
if (item.id === id) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  item.title = obj.title;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  item.body = obj.body;
}
```

And below is my test I am implementing which doesn't cover the IF statement, yet I see I have covered it:

```
it("should edit a Note.", () => {
  wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  $.fn.modal = jest.fn();
  wrapper.instance().onEditNote({ target: { value: "0" } });

  wrapper.instance().setState({
    title: "huxy 12",
    body: "hey huxy this is not great.",
    notesArray: [{ title: "hey", body: "its good", id: "0" }]
  });

  wrapper.instance().setState(state => {
    state.notesArray.map(item => {
      if (item.id === "0") {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        item.title = state.title;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        item.body = state.body;
      }
      return item;
    });
  });
});
```

What am I missing in my test?

**EDIT**
This is my edited test with **Jest Matchers** , doesn't work.

```
it('should edit a Note.', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    $.fn.modal = jest.fn();
    wrapper.instance().onEditNote({ target: { value: '0' } });

    wrapper.instance().setState({
      title: 'huxy 12',
      body: 'hey huxy this is not great.',
      notesArray: [{ title: 'hey', body: 'its good', id: '0' }],
    });

    wrapper.instance().setState((state) => {
      state.notesArray.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === '0') {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          item.title = state.title;
          expect(item.title).toBe(state.title);
          expect(item.title).not.toBeNull();
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          item.body = state.body;
        }
        return item;
      });
    });

    wrapper.instance().onEditNote({ target: { value: 0 } });
  });
```

This is the full state :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props, props, props);
    this.state = {
      notesArray: [],
      id: '',
      title: '',
      body: '',
      search: '',
      titleDisplay: '',
      bodyDisplay: '',
      titleError: '',
      bodyError: '',
    };
    this.onHandleSubmit = this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this test? It contains no assertions. It doesn't cover cover anything, not just `if`.

Comment: Thanks @estus, I have edited my question with jest matchers , but still the area isn't covered. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions shouldn't be placed inside `setState` callback. `setState` is supposed to be called on Enzyme wrapper, not an instance. Branches should be tested one by one, based on branch condition.

It should be something like:

```
wrapper = shallow(<App />);
// mock $(...).modal and localStorage.setItem
wrapper.setState({ title: '' });
wrapper.instance().onEditNote({ target: { value: '0' } });
expect(wrapper.state.titleError).toEqual({ title: '', titleError: ... );

wrapper = shallow(<App />);
// mock $(...).modal and localStorage.setItem
wrapper.setState({ title: '' });
wrapper.instance().onEditNote({ target: { value: '0' } });
expect(wrapper.state.titleError).toEqual({ body '', bodyError: ... );

// etc.
```

Globals shouldn't be generally mocked by assigning `jest.fn()` as this may prevent them from being cleaned up, a preferable way to mock `$(...).modal` is `jest.spy`.

`localStorage.setItem` needs to be mocked as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but I was dealing with `notesArray[]` in the state. Check in the EDIT section of my question , I have included the state.

Comment: You were basing on `titleError` and `bodyError`, but the values which I was changing are in notesArray. So this list contains the Objects of `title`, `id`, and `body`.
So when it's populated, it can be like this : `[{id:'0',title:"helllo","body:"am good"}]`.

Comment: *but the values which I was changing are in notesArray* - no, they aren't, check your code again. `notesArray` is changed only in `else`. I started from the beginning, testing one condition at time. You can add missing state keys to `toEqual`, or use `toMatchObject` to assertb only keys that are changed in onEditNote.

Answer (score 1):

```
I enhanced the following code  to test for 
const regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s-]+/;
```

to accept on comma and - and backSpace characters

```
stringGenerator = (length) => {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?:"}{}+,~&^$.\\||$3#@%&()';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};
```

regex.test(stringGenerator(7))